# Office 365 / EWS Authentication using OAuth: The audience claim value is invalid

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm still struggling with this.
Please see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892650/office-365-ews-authentication-using-oauth) for details.

I am doing an application (currently command line) which should access Office 365/Exchange through EWS Managed API. The goal is to authenticate through OAuth2.

I have registered an application in Azure AD.
I have used the ClientID from there
I generated an App Secret / Key
I have delegated the "Have full access to a users' mailbox (preview)" permissions to the App.

I am using ADAL to retrieve the Access Token like this:

```
var authority = "https://login.windows.net/<tenant>"
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var clientCredential = new ClientCredential("<clientId>", "<appKey>");
result = OAuthTokenManager.authContext.AcquireToken("<my ResourceID>", clientCredential);
```

I do get an access token back. The decoded value is:

```json
{
 "typ": "JWT",
 "alg": "RS256",
 "x5t": "kriMPdmBvx68skT8-mPAB3BseeA"
}.
{
 "aud": "<my resource ID>",
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/2d1f889d-7930-4ef6-9f87-ef096d91ac47/",
 "nbf": 1403253608,
 "exp": 1403296808,
 "sub": "bdb0baf9-29ca-4a43-b9f8-d81ca2ae83bd",
 "appid": "<my app ID>",
 "oid": "bdb0baf9-29ca-4a43-b9f8-d81ca2ae83bd",
 "tid": "2d1f889d-7930-4ef6-9f87-ef096d91ac47",
 "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/2d1f889d-7930-4ef6-9f87-ef096d91ac47/"
}.
[signature]
```

I then use this token to connect to EWS:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
var credentials = new OAuthCredentials(token);
service.Credentials = credentials;
service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "<smtp address of o365 mailbox>");
Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
```

The Folder.Bind fails with a 401 error.

In EWS Trace I can see this as the reason:

```
The audience claim value is invalid <my resource ID>
```

The resource ID is the "APP-ID-URI" from the registered application.

I'm sure I'm only missing a small details...  but I can't find it :)
Any pointers are much appreciated.

If I use https://outlook.office365.com/ as resource ID (aud), I get this error message:

```
ACS50001: Relying party with identifier 'https://outlook.office365.com/' was not found.
```

The Tenant does have an Exchange subscription, and it has full access to the mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok. With a service-type app, you're going to want to use a service account that can impersonate your users. See [this MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for details. Once you have that account, you'll want to authenticate via OAuth as that service account, then impersonate your users as needed.

With a native application, [you cannot use the app secret to authenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605895%28v=office.15%29.aspx#ConNavExample_develop). So you'll need to do something like:

```
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", clientId, new Uri(callbackUri), PromptBehavior.Auto);
```

Where `clientId` is your client ID from your Azure registration, and `callbackUri` is the redirect URI you specified when registering your app in Azure. This will cause a prompt window to show, but if you save the token and refresh token and use those to refresh, you should avoid any further prompts. The token you get back should look something like:

```
{
 "typ": "JWT",
 "alg": "RS256",
 "x5t": "kriMPdmBvx68skT8-mPAB3BseeA"
}.
{
 "aud": "https://outlook.office365.com",
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/9e4563d1-423e-493b-bdc5-9a98fe2e24d9/",
 "iat": 1403706230,
 "nbf": 1403706230,
 "exp": 1403710130,
 "ver": "1.0",
 "tid": "9e4563d1-423e-493b-bdc5-9a98fe2e24d9",
 "amr": [
  "pwd"
 ],
 "oid": "4a6e20e6-9711-4ca1-888b-34e63f65f897",
 "upn": "impersonationaccount@contoso.com",
 "unique_name": "impersonationaccount@contoso.com",
 "sub": "Pp3JW2dfYELMUBjGjUIZLarT4diOkkKZ1OJPVunzAYE",
 "puid": "100300008A9245F4",
 "family_name": "Account",
 "given_name": "Application",
 "appid": "<your app id>",
 "appidacr": "0",
 "scp": "user_impersonation",
 "acr": "1"
}.
[signature]
```

The app will authenticate as the impersonationaccount@contoso.com user, and then you can impersonate other users. I just tested this with my test Office 365 account using a little test console app.

One last final caveat: the OAuth permission scope required for EWS are not portable like the other permission scopes are. What I mean by that is that unlike a REST API app, where you can register it in Azure using your developer tenant, and then other Office 365 organizations can just consent to your app, EWS apps that use OAuth have to be registered separately in each tenant that uses them. If you're creating this app for your own organization, not so big a deal. But if you were planning on licensing this app to other organizations, something you should be aware of.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I was not aware of that (and the documentation does not seem to be very clear about it either). I'll try this approach then, thanks!

Comment: Understood about the documentation, and I appreciate the feedback. We're working on documentation for using OAuth with EWS specifically. It's still sort of new for us, I wasn't even sure impersonation would work with it! :)

Comment: So the "prompt" would be a prompt for a password? (which would unfortunately be useless for our type of app...)  any way we can provide the PW programatically?

Comment: No, you can't provide it programmatically, at least not that I'm aware of! The idea behind OAuth is that you're app never has the user's password. Could you do some sort of sign-on during initial config/install to obtain a token/refresh token combo? I believe if you did that, you'd never have to prompt for sign in again, as long as you refresh before the refresh token expires.

Comment: I'll try to think of something to work around that limitation. It should be possible to send the token to another app, I guess? We have a web UI application which "controls" services on different machines. Those services would need the token. So we could prompt the user for credentials in the WebUI and then send the token to the services to be used.

Comment: Please can you answer just one question in layman's terms. Is it possible to add/edit/delete calendar events using a script and not getting consent through a web browser?  We have our own internal applications with calendars and we would simple like to have the ability to add/edit/delete events on user's calendars with a python script.

Comment: "EWS apps that use OAuth have to be registered separately in each tenant that uses them."
I assume that rules out EWS for a SaaS offering supporting office365 (where the SaaS acts as client application)?

Answer (score 0):

Your "aud" parameter should be "https://outlook.office365.com". Try passing that to AcquireToken. You also shouldn't need to set ImpersonatedUserId. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Jason. I have tried that and get `ACS50001: Relying party with identifier 'https://outlook.office365.com/' was not found.` I need to impersonate, how else does he now to which mailbox to connect? (I'm using the AppId + App Secret as ClientCredentials)

Comment: The user identity is also in the token. OAuth flow is a little limited for EWS, but essentially as part of your token acquisition, the user is prompted to login, then that information is encapsulated in the token you get back, or at least has been in my experience with simple desktop type apps. Are you doing this from a web app?

Comment: No, this is a service type app. We only have admin consent. We need to be able to impersonate every user